# Magento Payment methods in admin panel gone missing

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

After re-installing a Paypal module, our Payment methods screen went weird, and I have no idea how to get it fixed. I reloaded the entire /app/design/adminhtml/ folder from the original magento compressed files that was used to install it, but still, no luck.

The block that is supposed to come up when you click on the "Configure" button for Paypal Express Checkout.

The block it is supposed to show has empty html elements in it, so I guess a Block is not being rendered somewhere.

I copied across the entire /app/design/adminhtml folder from another similar install, as well as /skin/adminhtml.

Screen looks like this:

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Is it a layout issue, design issue, data, or missing template files somewhere?

It should look like this:
[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try replacing `Mage/Paypal/Block/Adminhtml` might work

Comment: Tried that, it made no difference.

Comment: sorry if you've done this but have you tried clearing the cache (including APC cache), might have to turn the inspector on to see where it's trying to load the image to cross check its location.

Comment: Disabled and Cleared all cache. How do I turn on Inspector?
I believe the blocks are not being rendered at all, which means the images wont be showing either.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to try (obviously disable caching/APC/compilation/minification of JS,CSS/etc.):

**Logs & Developer Mode**

First I would enable developer mode via .htaccess SetEnv or simply uncommenting the flag in `index.php`. Also ensure that logging is enabled via the Admin. System->Configuration->Developer->Log Settings.  Also check `var/logs/` for any existing exception.log or system.log with possible information to issues.  It also doesn't hurt to check Apache and PHP's logs.

**Paypal and Magento debugging**

Something to note is since obviously Ebay has/had backing of Magento the Module is pretty highly customized, especially on the configuration, as you can tell.  Some key files to step through with something like XDebug would be:

`app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php` and the `..Paypal/Model/System/Config/*` directories and files, as these are what are driving some of the custom configuration options of the module. etc/system.xml is also an entry point to review as well for the modules configurations.

**Reverting to Stock**

**1)** Copy from a fresh version of the Paypal module from a Magento 1.7.x source archive (ensure its the same version you are running!)

copy the `app/code/core/Mage/Paypal` from the source archive

to `app/code/local/Mage/Paypal`

(NOTE: PaypalUk module may also be good to copy down to local as well)

This should be a quick and easy way to check if there any missing files, damaged/corrupted, and/or core file that was modified.

**2)** Revert all theme/skins to the `base/default` theme. A quick way to do this is System->Design->Add Design Change.

**3)** Make a backup of `core_config_data` and remove all instances of the `path` that contains paypal, payment and payflow.

`SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE '%paypal%' OR path LIKE '%payflow%' OR path LIKE '%payment%';`

This should revert any configuration changes previously done back to the defaults specified in the modules xml.

The point of most of these steps is to get the payment module back to as much stock as possible.

Hope this helps!

---

Sonassi has a good detailed fundamentals as well for debugging magento worth a read:

- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store/429#429

Comment: I am using the base default theme. just checked.

Comment: @ShaunOReilly you should take a snapshot of your production environment and run it locally to debug.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your developer toolbar and look for missing assets - it seems to me that it's looking in a different folder for the missing images. The Net tab will usually point out to the problem here (404s).
2. Try a chmod 777 to the entire Magento directory - check if it's a permission related issue and [return it to normal](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions)
3. Run a diff between your codebase and the vanilla Magento installation. I would start with the `app/design/adminhtml` directory. You can use a tool like [DiffMerge.](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/)
4. Disable your other installed extensions one by one by going to `app/etc/modules/` and deleting the XML files one by one (I believe this is better than changing the `<active>` node to `false`). Identify the results and restore the files.
5. Just in case, check for Javascript issues via your developer toolbar in your Magento admin.
6. If need be, try a different version of the PayPal module - make sure that it is compatible with your Magento version first.

Comment: it is not just the images that are missing, but the entire Paypal Express configuration block. I have the exact same Paypal module running in another install on the same server, which works perfectly. I believe someone accidentally deleted some files and folders in one of the directories, therefore the missing files, somewhere...

Comment: I checked permissions a while back, and have set everything to 777 already to rule out that option, thanks.

Comment: @ShaunOReilly then it's likely to be a layout XML related issue. Have you also tried overwriting your adminHTML layout XML files? Make sure nothing in `local.xml` overwrites the nodes/blocks either.

Comment: I have copied over all the Layout XML files for AdminHTML from the working installation to the broken one. I wish I could do some kind of directory/file compare / diff between the two installs, but I suspect that it will need to compare 22,000 files!

Comment: You only really need to compare a few select directories. I would start with `app/design/adminhtml`. There are tools that will let you diff directories like DiffMerge - http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/